# NSXMLParser and Searchbars

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsxmlparser

after requesting and parsing a xml file from a server with success, i wanted to add a little search bar at the top. So as i'am learning Objective-ci followed 3 maybe 4 tutorials on how to make a functional search bar, but didn't succeed. The problem is i don't know how to perform the sort in a NSMutableArray filled by NSXMLParser, i seek help please :

This is where i print my results :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 50);
    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    lbl1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    [lbl1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0]];
    [lbl1 setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
    lbl1.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"creation_date"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl1];
    [lbl1 release];

    CGRect frame2 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 50);
    UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame2];
    lbl2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    [lbl2 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0]];
    [lbl2 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    lbl2.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"name"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl2];
    [lbl2 release];

    if(!uploaded) 
    {
        CGRect frame2 = CGRectMake(48, 12, 250, 50);
        UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame2];
        lbl2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        [lbl2 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0]];
        [lbl2 setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        lbl2.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"owner_name"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl2];
        [lbl2 release];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: have a look at similar post found on the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608247/sorting-nsmutablearray-using-sortdescriptor-and-predicate-possible

Comment: You can sort an array using methods of NSArray (superclass for NSMutableArray):
    `– sortedArrayHint`
`– sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:`
`– sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:hint:`
`– sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`
`– sortedArrayUsingSelector:`
`– sortedArrayUsingComparator:`
`– sortedArrayWithOptions:usingComparator:`

Comment: Yeay thanks :D ! if you want you can edit an answer i will rate it the good one.